# if else condition in shell script to check empty input by user

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am taking input from the user, and wants that if user give empty input , it should display the error message , I am trying below code , please correct me where I am wrong  .

```
  #!/bin/bash
    echo "please enter previous version number"
    read prevversion
    echo "please enter new version number"
    read newversion
    echo "please enter environment [DEV2/QAT2/PPE2/PRD]"
    read env

    if[["$env"=" " &&"$prevversion"=" " &&"$newversion"= " "]]
    then
        echo "Please enter the details and try again"

    else

        if [ "$env" = "QAT2" ]
        then
                prevversion="$prevversion"_QAT2
                echo "previous version is $prevversion"
                newversion="$newversion"_QAT2
                echo "new version is $newversion"
                env="$env"
                echo "enviornment is $env"
        elif [ "$env" = "PPE2" ]
        then
                prevversion="$prevversion"
                echo "previous version is $prevversion"
                newversion="$newversion"
                echo "new version is $newversion"
                env="$env"
                echo "enviornment is $env"
        elif [ "$env" = "PRD" ]
        then
                prevversion="$prevversion"
                echo "previous version is $prevversion"
                newversion="$newversion"
                echo "new version is $newversion"
                env="$env"
                echo "enviornment is $env"
        elif [ "$env" = "DEV2" ]
        then
                prevversion="$prevversion"_DEV2
                echo "previous version is $prevversion"
                newversion="$newversion"_DEV2
                echo "new version is $newversion"
                env="$env"
                echo "enviornment is $env"
        fi


    fi
```

please provide me with correct solution

Comment: You need spaces around `[[` and `]]`.

Comment: Spaces are important delimiters in shell scripts; your first `if` condition is missing them in a bunch of places. Use [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) for spotting common mistakes like this.

Comment: I'm betting you didn't even run this script

Answer (score 1):

your are using '&&' in your if-condition which means, that the error-message is only displayed when every(!) input is empty:
`if[["$env"=" " &&"$prevversion"=" " &&"$newversion"= " "]]`

You should change it like that:

```
if [ -z "${env}" ] || [ -z "${prevversion}" ] || [ -z "${newversion}" ]; then
    echo "either one of the vars is empty"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `||`, not `&&`. And you should be testing against an empty string, not a string with a single space.

```
if [[ "$env" = "" || "$prevversion" = "" || "$newversion" = "" ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in the following way:

```
if [ -z "$env" ] || [ -z "$prevversion" ] || [ -z "$newversion" ]; then
    echo "either one of the vars is empty"
    exit 1
fi
```

this will check that at least one of the tree var is empty.
If this is the case `print` your error message and `exit` the script with `return code 1` to show that the script exit in error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-z` to check for an empty string, and don't repeat so much code.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Prompt for what should be command line arguments.  If
# the script is going to be used in a batch environment to read
# from a stream, then prompting is unhelpful.  If it is used
# in an interactive environment, it is easier to pass this
# data on the command line.
echo "please enter previous version number"
read prevversion
echo "please enter new version number"
read newversion
echo "please enter environment [DEV2/QAT2/PPE2/PRD]"
read env

if test -z "$env" || test -z "$prevversion" || test -z "$newversion"; then
        echo "Please enter the details and try again" >&2
        exit 1
fi

case "$env" in
QAT2)
        prevversion="$prevversion"_QAT2
        newversion="$newversion"_QAT2
;;
PPE2)
        prevversion="$prevversion"
        newversion="$newversion"
;;
PRD)
        prevversion="$prevversion"
        newversion="$newversion"
;;
DEV2)
        prevversion="$prevversion"_DEV2
        newversion="$newversion"_DEV2
;;
esac
echo "previous version is $prevversion"
echo "new version is $newversion"
echo "enviornment is $env"
```